# Windows Universal App SerialDevice communication not sending/recieving data

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, win-universal-app

I am working on a Universal Windows 10 App which communicates with an Arduino device.  *I do not want to remotely control the Arduino.*  I want to simply send and receive data to and from the device.  I have tried several methods of doing this to no avail.  Here is what I am trying now:

```cs
SerialDevice tempDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(devices.ElementAt(i).Id);

tempDevice.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
tempDevice.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
tempDevice.BaudRate = 115200;
tempDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;
tempDevice.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
tempDevice.DataBits = 8;
tempDevice.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
tempDevice.IsRequestToSendEnabled = true;
DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(tempDevice.OutputStream);

dataWriter.WriteString("Test string");
await dataWriter.FlushAsync(); // <-- program hangs here

testDevice.Dispose();
```

I am using `Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.SerialDevice` and `Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter`

I have added various breakpoints around the marked line and determined that the program was hanging there.  I have even tried removing the `await` keyword, and the program still hangs at the same line.  Why am I unable to send data to the Arduino?

There are a few things I do not understand, IN ADDITION to why it is not working altogether:

- First, why does the application halt there, if the method is asynchronous? (Like I said, I have tried removing the `await` keyword)
- Secondly, why doesn't it give up after 1000 milliseconds (1 second), since the timeout is set at 1000 milliseconds?

I am using an Arduino Mega 2560 and the program is Windows 10 Universal App coded in C#.

Comment: What device does your Windows 10 Universal App run on? What is your serial port chip?

Comment: @RitaHan, I am running the app on a Lenovo ThinkPad laptop s230u.  As for the aerial port chip, I'm not sure I'll have to check when I get home

Comment: @vcapra1, Interesting that I always get Method not implemented exception when calling await dataWriter.FlushAsync().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add pause after opening port and before DataWriter creation:

```
 Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
```

Here is my checked working method:

```
private async Task sendToPort(string sometext)
    {

using (SerialDevice serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId))
        {
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait(); 

            if ((serialPort != null) && (sometext.Length != 0))
            {
                serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
                serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
                serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();

                try
                {

using (DataWriter dataWriteObject = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream))
                    {

                        Task<UInt32> storeAsyncTask;

                        dataWriteObject.WriteString(sometext);

                        storeAsyncTask = dataWriteObject.StoreAsync().AsTask();

                        UInt32 bytesWritten = await storeAsyncTask;

                        if (bytesWritten > 0)
                        {
                            txtStatus.Text = bytesWritten + " bytes written";
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    txtStatus.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why?  How does this help?

Comment: That's some opening port issue. Not sure, but might be something with DTR.

Comment: Ahh, this worked.  Actually, the delay was not the problem, as it now works without the delay.  However, something to do with the code inside the try-catch block now makes it work.  Thank you!

Comment: this is very old, but I'd like to say that StoreAsync was the missing call! I thought writestring was all you need to send something, apparently not.